# Making Text Boxes Aligned

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I am having an issue right now. When I load up my webpage, all of the boxes/words are aligned awkwardly, and I was wondering if I can get some help aligning the boxes all to be on the same line.

[click here for a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cXfRr/)

```
<table bgcolor="#bbbbbb" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="center">
    <tr>
    <td width="10%" valign="top" align="center">
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
        <font size="5"><strong>Account Login</strong></font><br />
        Username :
        <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"><br />
        Password :
        <input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"> <br />
        &nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        <input style="width:75px; font-size:14px; height:25px;" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </td>
    <td width="10%" valign="top" align="center">
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="registration_script.php">
        <font size="5"><strong>Account Register</strong></font><br />
        Username :
        <input type="text" name="txtUser" id="txtUser" /> <br />
        Repeat :
        <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"><br />
        Password :
        <input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" /> <br />
        Repeat :
        <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"><br />
        <input style="width:75px; font-size:14px; height:25px;" type="submit" name="btnRegister" id="btnRegister" value="Register" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: How about posting a screenshot and/or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) illustrating the problem?

Comment: You need to add cells or some form of division to your text and input fields.  The input fields look funny because they start right after the text and your td is aligned center, so everything is aligning center inside your td.

Answer (score 1):

try to check this one: [Edited](http://jsfiddle.net/Vainglory07/cXfRr/3/)

hope this gives the idea(on my own very way:)).

```
 <table bgcolor="#bbbbbb" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="center">
<tr>
<td width="10%" valign="top" align="center">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <table>
        <thead align="center">Account Login</thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Username :</td>
            <td><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="1"><input style="width:75px; font-size:14px; height:25px;" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</td>
<td width="10%" valign="top" align="center">
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="registration_script.php">
    <table>
        <thead align="center">Account Register</thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Username :</td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="txtUser" id="txtUser" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Repeat :</td>
            <td><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Repeat :</td>
            <td><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="1"><input style="width:75px; font-size:14px; height:25px;" type="submit" name="btnRegister" id="btnRegister" value="Register" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
```

​

Answer (score 0):

you can define you own css to define the alignment

for example:

```
<style>
 selector{
  float:left;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't mind tableless:

```
<style>
    .pseudo-table, form p {
        display: table;
        background-color: #bbbbbb;
    }

    .pseudo-cell, form p label {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    form p label {
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>

<div class='pseudo-table'>
    <div class='pseudo-cell'>
        <form name='form1' method='post' action='checklogin.php'>
        <h2>Account Login</h2>
        <p>
            <label>Username</label>
            : <input name='myusername' type='text' id='myusername'>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            : <input name='mypassword' type='password' id='mypassword'>
        </p>
        <button>Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class='pseudo-cell'>
        <form name='form2' method='post' action='registration_script.php'>
        <h2>Account Register</h2>
        <p>
            <label>Username</label>
            : <input type='text' name='txtUser' id='txtUser'>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Repeat</label>
            : <input name='myusername' type='text' id='myusername'>
        </label>
        <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            : <input type='password' name='txtPassword' id='txtPassword'>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Repeat</label>
            : <input name='myusername' type='text' id='myusername'>
        </p>
        <button>Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```